USG unable to be installed
I tried to get ubuntu pro for my personal Ubuntu virtual machine
The i get the token of 'myself Ubuntu pro as free' and attach it in the terminal
but i got this error

tri@tri-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-security-guide
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-security-guide


how to solove this problem?

I don't it's a package meant to be installed separately. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/comply-with-cis-or-disa-stig-on-ubuntu#4-enabling-the-ubuntu-security-guide indicates it's supposed to be a part of ubuntu-pro itself (which you should already have if you did "attach it in the terminal")

i show the status of pro but the usg is not enabled @muru

The correct name of the package is usg, not ubuntu-security-guide. That's why you got an Unable to locate package ubuntu-security-guide error message.
Enabling the Ubuntu Security Guide leads you through the following two step process which involves running first sudo pro enable usg and after that sudo apt install usg as shown below.
$ sudo pro enable usg
One moment, checking your subscription first
Updating package lists
USG enabled

$ sudo apt install usg

